# Link style in electron application

Tags: css, webpack, electron

I have application generated with electron-forge cli with webpack template. My files structure is:

[image]

I'm trying to add some styles to index.html but it doesn't work as expected. I tried to add in `<head>` of index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css">
```

not working. I also tried to add:

```
import '../css/index.css'
```

to renderer/js/index.js (since it's bundled by webpack anyway) but it also doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong? Is the path to stylesheet not correct in my index.html head because of using webpack?

Comment: Is `import` statement throwing any error ?

Comment: can you show the webpack configuration file?

Comment: nope it is not throwing any error. Yes I can show configuration files, but I got 3 of them and also entrypoint in package.json so I'm gonna paste it as gist: https://gist.github.com/BorysTyminski/93e23040c4c89f1216bd08f76ccfe9a1

Comment: It seems like there is no CSS loader, I might  be wrong but I would try to add it https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

Comment: Okey but what about adding stylesheet in traditional way by link tag in index.html